# Android Log in Application to website

Tags: android, cookies, authentication, parameters, http-post

So iam trying to get a successful log in from this server : www.liuserver.com and im using two classes LoginLayout.java and CustomHttpclient.java , now i have monitored the browser communication with the sever using Httpwatch in order to track the kind of reply the server produces and the post(which produces url containing username and password provided by the user in addition to x and y integers automatically generated which are 31 and 1 in this example and other times hey are just zeroes) the post to the webpage look like this :

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap,     application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Referer: https://www.liuserver.com/login.php
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR     3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.liuserver.com
Content-Length: 38
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: PHPSESSID=e3q4d78jkci3shhn8fq1tlf7i5

USER=20730312&PASS=Password44&x=32&y=1
```

now i have succeeded to generate the url with the parameters and i am posting them to the server but of course it gives me negative reply , now i have been told and it is obvious in the cookies tab in the httpwatch plugin that i need to send the phpsessionid as a cookie and here comes my question how am be able to do this and in which class should i place the code for sending the cookie with the parameters, and how can i be track the kind of reply from the server upon successful verification of the username and password.
the reply stream looks like :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.0.14
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 15:57:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: student/
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Content-Length: 0
```

the full url to log in page :`https://www.liuserver.com/login.php`

Update :

Ok i have succeeded to get the phpsessionid cookie from the server and i can view it's value , now i have to submit my log in parameters to the erver using

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("https://www.liuserver.com/login.php", postParameters);
```

but where should i place the cookie that contains phpsession id in this method executehttpPost can i change the parameters of the method and pass the cookie there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save cookies you need something along the lines of:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();
ctx.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("your URL here");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get,ctx);
```

And if you want to keep cookies between requests, you have to reuse `cookieStore` and `ctx` for every request.

Also, you may read your `cookieStore` to see what's inside:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
if( !cookies.isEmpty() ){
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies){
        String cookieString = cookie.getName() + " : " + cookie.getValue();
        Log.info(TAG, cookieString);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply , i have a related question here say i have made the httpget to the server how can verify that the application received the cookie ? in other words how can i read the reply from the server to the application ?

Comment: Thanks @lenik for your reply this was really helpful , now i am storing the cookie and can read it's content using cookie manager , but i still don't know how should i pass the cookie to the server along with the parameters in an equivalent to the code i have listed in my question , should it be just a string or a urlencoded value pair entity ?

Comment: As long as you use same `BasicCookieStore` and pass `HttpContext`, associated with that cookie store along with every request as `httpclient.execute( request, httpcontext)`, your cookies wiill be automatically supplied to server, you don't have to worry about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie is passed as part of the headers in the HTTP reply (just like in your POST) if you want to play with the headers directly.

But like the other poster says, how to deal with cookies (properly) is in the example he has posted, and it will ultimately help you to use the API properly, even though it may be a pain to learn how it works the first time around :-)